# ¿Como mostrar en pantalla una fila de una matriz? C++

Tags: c++, array, matrices, dev-c++, c++98

Comunidad, les pido la ayuda con un pequeño problema. Estoy recién aprendiendo C++ y he estado trabajando con arreglos y matrices, entiendo la lógica de como imprimir una matriz y como recorre sus contenidos, pero hay cosas que aún no las puedo resolver. Necesito imprimir una fila o una columna de una matriz con 10 columnas y 5 filas lo unico que me falta hacer es imprimir una columna o una fila que el usuario desee, ejemplo: si el usuario me dice que quiere que le muestre en pantalla la fila 1 del arreglo dimensional el programa tiene que hacer eso lo mismo si quiere ver la columna 3 por ejemplo, se que se haria con un for creo para cada caso pero como seria?

Comment: ¿Has probado con `std::cout`?

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El algoritmo para imprimir una determinada fila pedida por el usuario es:**

- Pides por teclado el valor de la fila.
- Ejecutas un bucle for donde su condición será verdadera hasta que la variable acumuladora sea diferente de 10 (porqué en este caso, la cantidad máxima de columnas es 10).

**Para las columnas es casi el mismo proceso:**

- Pides por teclado el valor de la columna.
- Ejecutas un bucle for donde su condición será verdadera hasta que la variable acumuladora sea diferente de 5 (porqué en este caso, la cantidad máxima de filas es 5).

En código sería:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define MAX_FILAS       5
#define MAX_COLUMNAS    5

int main()
{
    int fila, columna;
    int matriz[MAX_FILAS][MAX_COLUMNAS] = {0};
    std::string opcion;
    std::cout << "Ingrese (f)/(c) si desea imprimir una fila o columna" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> opcion;
    if(opcion == "f")
    {
        std::cout << "Que fila quieres imprimir?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> fila;
        for(columna = 0; columna != MAX_COLUMNAS; ++columna)
            std::cout << matriz[fila][columna] << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Que columna quieres imprimir?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> columna;
        for(fila = 0; fila != MAX_FILAS; ++fila)
            std::cout << matriz[fila][columna] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Al código le falta validaciones, pero igual sólo quise poner más énfasis en como se imprime los valores de una fila o columna que desee el usuario.